# What does strip() consider whitespace?

Tags: python, whitespace

Python's `strip` functions remove whitespace by default.

What is Python's whitespace?

Is it same as `isspace` in C/C++, i.e. includes new line, vertical tab, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

Python's definition of whitespace, as used by `str.strip` and `str.isspace`, [is as follows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace):

> A character is *whitespace* if in the Unicode character database (see [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata)), either its general category is `Zs` (“Separator, space”), or its bidirectional class is one of `WS`, `B`, or `S`.

This is different from C's `isspace`, as it includes Unicode characters outside the ASCII range, as well as a few ASCII characters that C's `isspace` does not count as whitespace. It is also different from `string.whitespace`, even for ASCII characters.

As of CPython 3.8.1, the complete list (as defined in the source code, and subject to change) [is as follows](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/unicodetype_db.h#L6148):

```
/* Returns 1 for Unicode characters having the bidirectional
 * type 'WS', 'B' or 'S' or the category 'Zs', 0 otherwise.
 */
int _PyUnicode_IsWhitespace(const Py_UCS4 ch)
{
    switch (ch) {
    case 0x0009:
    case 0x000A:
    case 0x000B:
    case 0x000C:
    case 0x000D:
    case 0x001C:
    case 0x001D:
    case 0x001E:
    case 0x001F:
    case 0x0020:
    case 0x0085:
    case 0x00A0:
    case 0x1680:
    case 0x2000:
    case 0x2001:
    case 0x2002:
    case 0x2003:
    case 0x2004:
    case 0x2005:
    case 0x2006:
    case 0x2007:
    case 0x2008:
    case 0x2009:
    case 0x200A:
    case 0x2028:
    case 0x2029:
    case 0x202F:
    case 0x205F:
    case 0x3000:
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it includes newline and vertical tab.  The full definition is accessible as string.whitespace.

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html?highlight=whitespace#string.whitespace